# Rim Problem with Solidify Modifier

Tags: modifiers

I have a 3D egg model in blender. I seperate it from half and i want it to be solid. I try to use solidify modifer but there is weird looking problem. It's not match with other half. If i didn't check fill rim it's okay but i want rim filled too. Thanks!! (Sorry for my bad english)

[image]

Comment: Looks like a problem with smooth shading - try adding an Edge Split modifier.

Comment: Just noticed you've already got one - try moving it below the Solidify.

Comment: @RichSedman Thank you soo much moving it below solved the problem.

Comment: Excellent - glad to help. I've added this as an answer.

Comment: Your English is fine my friend : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence of the modifiers is important here. Move the Edge Split modifier to below the Solidify modifier - the modifiers are applied in sequence so this way the edge split is applied to the result of the solidify.