# I have a problem with splitting an object

Tags: shadows

I'm doing an illusion kind of animation, where a rules is split in two and where the other part is closer to the camera than the other, but they should seem to be connected at first. The camera will slide showing that the two parts are actually not attached.

[image]

My problem is a line which is created by a shadow in the front part. It breaks the illusion of the parts and i don't know what creates this shadow as it cannot be erased with a light.

[image]

I made the 2 parts of the ruler by duplicating the object then created 2 cubes and used them as masks with boolean to create the 2 parts.

Any Ideas what creates the shadow and how to remove it?

Comment: It looks to me to be a problem with smooth shading as in https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/88654/29586.

Comment: It would be easier to diagnose if you could include the .blend file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/